# Unable to load .net 3.5 after installing VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project P1 made using VS2008 and using .Net 3.5. It compiles fine, no issues. Then I made snapshot of the OS and installed VS2010. Now P1 does not compile with VS2008. Error I get is this.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3246:  
Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. Could not 
load file or assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.dll
```

I have following folders (OS Win2008 R2, SP1)

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319



C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

Please let me know what is going on. If I roll back snapshot everything works.

Comment: I fetched the project P1 afresh from TFS, then I was able to compile with VS2008 on machine that also had VS2010. So seems the project P1 was not right. Fetching from TFS corrected it. Thanks to Reed for responding.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your project was converted and updated to use .NET 4.  It's referencing the .NET 4.0 version of `System.dll`, not the .NET 3.5 version.

If you edit your project to target .NET 3.5, and make sure that all of the referenced assemblies also target .NET 3.5, it should work correctly.

Note that the *C# project files themselves* are not compatible between VS 2008 and VS 2010.  Version compatibility of projects was a new feature in VS 2010 sp1 and forward (so you can share between VS 2012 and VS 2010 sp1), but does not work with VS 2008.